# Localizing existing app's title in App Store?

Tags: localization, app-store

I have an app just released onto the App Store; for its first update I'd like to try localization, including having the App's title localized in some non-English locales (as well as strings, etc.). Anyone know if I can I change the titles in the foreign App Stores with the update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, in iTunes Connect you can edit metadata for your update.

When you add a version you must provide the new update version number and a description of what's changed, this is some information in English.

Then you're taken to the page to upload your binary and set other options such as release date etc... here there is a section called "Metadata and Uploads" which is for the app name, description, keywords, support URL, screenshots upload etc...

Here you can add localizations which lets you change choose an app name for each localization.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Daniel, helps a great deal! I guess this probably involves creating screenshot sets for other languages too.

Comment: Yes this is in that localized section for sure, although I'd like to try that out, it's interesting to see that for example the Facebook app doesn't or at least they didn't bother to localize their screenshots.